# There was an error loading your app! This app did not load because there appears to be something wrong with it

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

I am trying to create a Google+ hangout app.

I set up all fields in Google API console  Enabled the Google+ hangout to my API's.  When I am trying to add my hangout app to my hangout video call.

I am getting error like

> There was an error loading your app! This app did not load because
>   there appears to be something wrong with it.

my XML source file is  [here](https://github.com/madhusudhan518/demohangoutapp/blob/master/public/demohangoutapp.xml<br/)

When my hangout app trying to download in hangout, my rails server getting error like

```
ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00�\x01\x00\x00�\x03\x03y\bA黉̉EI�\x02\x06�p4�B8t\a�?붜��\x12�'.<br/>
ERROR bad URI `��T��\x15d"�\x0F��䃠\x7F�W'�Y�P�=\x00\x00\x1E�'
```

can anyone help me to come out of these.

when server asking for  localhost:3000/demohangoutapp.html ,             in browser network tab  the URL header contains Request URL:
    "https://localhost:3000/demohangoutapp.html?parent=https%3A%2F%2Fg7vvv07ifja6kfh7hlbpuen02gi410ue-a-hangout-opensocial.googleusercontent.com%2Fgadgets%2Fifr%3Furl%3Dapp%253A%252F%252F1089532940946%252Fhangout%26container%3Dhangout%26view%3Ddefault%26lang%3Dall%26country%3DALL%26debug%3D0%26nocache%3D1%26sanitize%3D0%26v%3De9f67d65d3c45721%26testmode%3D0%26parent%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fplus.google.com%26mid%3D1%26authuser%3D0%26hl%3Den%23st%3De%253DABul2V3342qYiNrtSKZaSOoxnVJcmjYLxlJqb%25252Btr8Am84%25252BAj6kYeDXuwqhkxsc5gE64NMBK9CbLIe77j9bOYVgOG9p9z24qCc4Pg6E3usS1oDG%25252F16daISnblUWzGg7XMSklgB5cfXZ2P%2526c%253Dhangout%26view-params%3D%257B%2522applicationUrl%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252Fhangoutiframer.appspot.com%252Fforward%252Fv0.2%253Fu%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fdemohangoutapp.html%2522%252C%2522appData%2522%253A%2522Hangouts%2522%257D&token=ya29.VQGN9n0LHGvwCD0CpORWgLMF3XX7xaExyl7mD_WjtcLbT4ie9uxFW9eIrPsYmRDxHebwSTs-RkGOHQ&gd=Hangouts" 
and response is failed to load

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Exchange network. You’ll have a much better chance of getting good answers if your question is clearer, shows what you’ve tried, what errors you got, etc. Be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you show the source of your xml file?

Comment: yes, @Scarygami. https://github.com/madhusudhan518/demohangoutapp/blob/master/public/demohangoutapp.xml you can find my xml source here.

Comment: @Scarygami  i followed your article http://life.scarygami.net/hangoutapps/ ,but i am getting error

Comment: Unfortunately this article is very outdated by now (I really have to update it sometime...). See my answer for the fix.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [your source](https://github.com/madhusudhan518/demohangoutapp/blob/master/public/demohangoutapp.xml#L9) the issue is that your link to the Hangouts API JS is wrong/outdated.

The currently valid link is https://plus.google.com/hangouts/_/api/v1/hangout.js

Changing this link should fix the issue.

Comment: i updated the js file source, but no change in my error.<br/> i added [this URl](https://hangoutiframer.appspot.com/forward/v0.2?u=https://localhost:3000/demohangoutapp.html) in application url in my google console.

Comment: when  my hangout app trying to download, i am getting errors in rails  server as                                                                                              ERROR bad URI `��T��\x15d"�\x0F��䃠\x7F�W'�Y�P�=\x00\x00\x1E�'.                                                                      ERROR bad Request-Line `\x16\x03\x01\x00�\x01\x00\x00�\x03\x03y\bA黉̉EI�\x02\x06�p4�B8t\a�?붜��\x12�'.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with your rails server setup (which I can't help you with since I have no idea about rails). Can you verify that https://localhost:3000/demohangoutapp.html displays correctly without errors for you?

Comment: yes, when i verify  https://localhost:3000/demohangoutapp.html , this page showing error "SSL connection error". and my server getting error like above in mentioned.